# Find the largest file in a Synology NAS drive

Tags: linux, unix, nas, synology

I'm trying to find out in a Linux terminal on my Synology NAS drive, how to see how much space is taken up by directories labeled as `eadir`. For those not familiar, these are basically metadata files that get used in media applications, web apps, etc. on the front-end of the NAS drive.

so far I navigated to my root `/volume1/` directory and have tried:

`du -h` -> Took a very long time, not sorted by file size.

`du -h > output.txt` -> This actually put all the information in a file, still not sorted by file size.

`du -h > output.txt | sort` -> sorted the files purely numerically, so a 10GB file would show up before a 20KB file just because numerically 10 is less than 20.

What other ways can I try to find out the largest files on my drive?

Comment: What about `sort -h -r`: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sort.1.html?

Comment: Sorry, just to add I also tried `du -sh * | sort -h > output.txt` and got an empty file.

Comment: Since you should not use `-s` but `-a`?

Comment: See this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22432/getting-size-with-du-of-files-only

Comment: Tried the command in there with `less` in it, but there's not a `less` command on the synology drive. Apparently there's not even apt-get, yum, etc either.

Comment: `less` is optional. It just allow you to read the result (and scroll back and forth) without writing it to a file. You can replace `| less` with `> output.txt`.

Comment: it apparently does not work unless i surround it with ' ' and type `sudo sh -c` before the command to run it in a new shell. Then I get a blinking cursor for a while.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37987/discussion-between-tom-yan-and-lord-missingno).

Answer (score 2):

You can install the Synology **Storage Analyzer** package.

Create a report, check ***Large Files*** report item (check all options, *Duplicate Files*, etc., they are all interesting).
Then run your report, it did not take long on my DS213+.

---

And, as Germar said, `ncdu` is also a very convenient and interactive solution.

To make it scan your folders faster, without using network,
You can install `ncdu` on your Synology NAS directly, and then run it through an SSH connection.
For this, [SynoCommunity package repo](https://synocommunity.com) to your Package Center and then install `ncdu` package.

Answer (score 0):

`ncdu` does exactly what you want and a lot more. You can even browse folders and also delete files directly.

[image: ncdu]